# Where to find a replacement spring for the sustain pedal on my baby grand?

Tags: piano, repair, keyboard-pedals

I recently changed houses, and in the move, the movers somehow dropped and lost the return spring for the sustain pedal on my *Story & Clark* baby grand. Is there a good place I can find one?

Answer (score 1):

Contact a local technician. After moving a piano it is normal to have it serviced by a technician anyway. Alternatively, contact the [manufacturer](http://www.qrsmusic.com/sc/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

If it's what I'm thinking of, search for "grand piano trap lever spring".  Be aware that they can make the pedal feel too heavy -- you might need to grind away some material and/or bend it to adjust.